# Using terraform yamldecode to access multi level element

Tags: yaml, terraform

I have a yaml file (also used in a azure devops pipeline so needs to be in this format) which contains some settings I'd like to directly access from my terraform module.

The file looks something like:

```
variables:
  - name: tenantsList
    value: tenanta,tenantb
  - name: unitName
    value: canary
```

I'd like to have a module like this to access the settings but I can't see how to get to the bottom level:

```
locals {
  settings = yamldecode(file("../settings.yml"))
}

module "infra" {
  source = "../../../infra/terraform/"
  unitname = local.settings.variables.unitName
}
```

But the `terraform plan` errors with this:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on canary.tf line 16, in module "infra":
  16:   unitname  = local.settings.variables.unitName
    |----------------
    | local.settings.variables is tuple with 2 elements

This value does not have any attributes.
```

Comment: Your YAML variable `variables` is a list, not a map so you would need to either change the data structure or access it as a list.

Comment: do you mean something like `unitname = element(local.settings.variables,1)` because I tried that and got: `The given value is not suitable for child module variable "unitname"
defined at ..\..\..\infra\terraform\variables.tf:7,1-27: string required.` so it appears it isn't getting the value successfully, but very hard to see what it is getting

Comment: That would then give you a map of `{name = unitName, value = canary}`. If you wanted the value `canary` there then you'd want to use `local.settings.variables.1.value`. But this seems fragile as a way of accessing that data. I'd consider changing your YAML input to be `variables = { "tenantsList" = "tenanta,tenantb", "unitName" = "canary" }` so you can then access it as `local.settings.variables.unitName` which is much clearer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like the main reason this is difficult is because this YAML file is representing what is logically a single map but is physically represented as a YAML list of maps.

When reading data from a separate file like this, I like to write an explicit expression to normalize it and optionally transform it for more convenient use in the rest of the Terraform module. In this case, it seems like having `variables` as a map would be the most useful representation as a Terraform value, so we can write a transformation expression like this:

```
locals {
  raw_settings = yamldecode(file("${path.module}/../settings.yml"))
  settings = {
    variables = tomap({
      for v in local.raw_settings.variables : v.name => v.value
    })
  }
}
```

The above uses a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions) to project the list of maps into a single map using the `name` values as the keys.

With the list of maps converted to a single map, you can then access it the way you originally tried:

```
module "infra" {
  source = "../../../infra/terraform/"
  unitname = local.settings.variables.unitName
}
```

If you were to *output* the transformed value of `local.settings` as YAML, it would look something like this, which is why accessing the map elements directly is now possible:

```
variables:
  tenantsList: tenanta,tenantb
  unitName: canary
```

This will work only if all of the `name` strings in your input are unique, because otherwise there would not be a unique map key for each element.

---

(Writing a normalization expression like this also doubles as some implicit validation for the shape of that YAML file: if `variables` were not a list or if the values were not all of the same type then Terraform would raise a type error evaluating that expression. Even if no transformation is required, I like to write out this sort of expression anyway because it serves as some documentation for what shape the YAML file is expected to have, rather than having to study all of the references to it throughout the rest of the configuration.)

Answer (score 2):

With my multidecoder for YAML and JSON you are able to access multiple YAML and/or JSON files with their relative paths in one step.

Documentations can be found here:

### Terraform Registry -

https://registry.terraform.io/modules/levmel/yaml_json/multidecoder/latest?tab=inputs

### GitHub:

https://github.com/levmel/terraform-multidecoder-yaml_json

### Usage

Place this module in the location where you need to access multiple different YAML and/or JSON files (different paths possible) and pass
your path/-s in the parameter **filepaths** which takes a set of strings of the relative paths of YAML and/or JSON files as an argument. You can change the module name if you want!

```
module "yaml_json_decoder" {
  source  = "levmel/yaml_json/multidecoder"
  version = "0.2.1"
  filepaths = ["routes/nsg_rules.yml", "failover/cosmosdb.json", "network/private_endpoints/*.yaml", "network/private_links/config_file.yml", "network/private_endpoints/*.yml", "pipeline/config/*.json"]
}
```

#### Patterns to access YAML and/or JSON files from relative paths:

To be able to access all YAML and/or JSON files in a folder entern your path as follows `"folder/rest_of_folders/*.yaml"`, `"folder/rest_of_folders/*.yml"` or `"folder/rest_of_folders/*.json"`.

To be able to access a specific YAML and/or a JSON file in a folder structure use this `"folder/rest_of_folders/name_of_yaml.yaml"`, `"folder/rest_of_folders/name_of_yaml.yml"` or `"folder/rest_of_folders/name_of_yaml.json"`

If you like to select all YAML and/or JSON files within a folder, then you should use **"*.yml"**, **"*.yaml"**, **"*.json"** format notation. (see above in the USAGE section)

#### YAML delimiter support is available from version 0.1.0!

**WARNING:** Only the relative path must be specified. The path.root (it is included in the module by default) should not be passed, but everything after it.

### Access YAML and JSON entries

Now you can access all entries within all the YAML and/or JSON files you've selected like that: **"module.yaml_json_decoder.files.[name of your YAML or JSON file].entry"**. If the name of your YAML or JSON file is "name_of_your_config_file" then access it as follows **"module.yaml_json_decoder.files.name_of_your_config_file.entry"**.

### Example of multi YAML and JSON file accesses from different paths (directories)

#### first YAML file:

routes/nsg_rules.yml

```
rdp:
  name: rdp
  priority: 80
  direction: Inbound
  access: Allow
  protocol: Tcp
  source_port_range: "*"
  destination_port_range: 3399
  source_address_prefix: VirtualNetwork
  destination_address_prefix: "*"
  
---
  
ssh:
  name: ssh
  priority: 70
  direction: Inbound
  access: Allow
  protocol: Tcp
  source_port_range: "*"
  destination_port_range: 24
  source_address_prefix: VirtualNetwork
  destination_address_prefix: "*"
```

#### second YAML file:

services/logging/monitoring.yml

```
application_insights:
  application_type: other
  retention_in_days: 30
  daily_data_cap_in_gb: 20
  daily_data_cap_notifications_disabled: true
  logs:
  # Optional fields
   - "AppMetrics"
   - "AppAvailabilityResults"
   - "AppEvents"
   - "AppDependencies"
   - "AppBrowserTimings"
   - "AppExceptions"
   - "AppExceptions"
   - "AppPerformanceCounters"
   - "AppRequests"
   - "AppSystemEvents"
   - "AppTraces"
```

#### first JSON file:

test/config/json_history.json

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main.tf

```
module "yaml_json_multidecoder" {
  source  = "levmel/yaml_json/multidecoder"
  version = "0.2.1"
  filepaths = ["routes/nsg_rules.yml", "services/logging/monitoring.yml", test/config/*.json]
}

output "nsg_rules_entry" {
  value = module.yaml_json_multidecoder.files.nsg_rules.aks.ssh.source_address_prefix
}

output "application_insights_entry" {
  value = module.yaml_json_multidecoder.files.monitoring.application_insights.daily_data_cap_in_gb
}

output "json_history" {
  value = module.yaml_json_multidecoder.files.json_history.glossary.title
}
```

---

Changes to Outputs:

- nsg_rules_entry            = "VirtualNetwork"
- application_insights_entry = 20
- json_history               = "example glossary"

Comment: That's a super handy bit of code to read yaml files Levon. Is there a way to search for *.yaml files recursively inside a folder?

Comment: @ArunANayagam Thank you my friend! In version 0.0.4 ```"*.yaml"``` and ```"*.yml"``` files can be selected. If you need more information regarding the "multiple yamldecode module" then please visit my GitHub repository or Terraform Registry. I've updated my answer here.

Comment: HI @Levon did you mean, "**.yaml"

Comment: Hi @ArunANayagam no, I mean ```"*.yaml"```.